# What is the female equivalent for 「ご主人様」 or "master?"

Tags: words, word-requests, gender

In *The Lion, the Witch, and the Wardrobe* novel, the character Aslan orders centaurs and eagles to chase a wolf, saying, "He will be going to his **mistress**."  He is referring to the wolf's female master, the White Witch, who considers herself to be the "Queen."  The witch refers to a dwarf as her "slave," so she has a master/slave relationship with her followers. What is the correct Japanese word for a dominant female "master?"

I tried searching in online Japanese dictionaries for the word "mistress," but the results seem to be comprised of Japanese words for "mistress" as in an extra-marital lover, or "madam" as in a well-bred lady, rather than a woman who has slaves/servants. When I searched for the word "master," I could not find words that fit females.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The female equivalent of 主人 is [女主人]{おんなしゅじん}, and you would address your 女主人 as [奥様]{おくさま} or お[嬢様]{じょうさま}.  (You wouldn't address her as [女主人様]{おんなしゅじんさま}.)

Comment: 奥様 is normally for a married lady, お嬢様 is for a young/single lady.

Comment: Just for clarification, OP may be wondering if it's possible to use something more specific, like 女主人様, to address a mistress, because お嬢様/奥様 is generic terms. And I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Right, you wouldn't call your 女主人 as 女主人様.

Comment: And, why the downvote (again, as usual?)